# R Reshape function when combinations doesn't exist

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to reshape my data from Long to wide, my initial dataframe looks like this:

```
    Crop              Partner     DM  SD_DM
   <fct>             <fct>    <dbl>  <dbl>
   1 GR                GR      2.90   0.771 
   2 IK                IK      2.79   0.279 
   3 LU                LU      3.01   0.337 
   4 LU_GR_50_50       GR      2.24   0.477 
   5 LU_GR_50_50       LU      0.706  0.458 
  6 LU_GR_75_25       GR      1.85   0.145 
  7 LU_GR_75_25       LU      1.63   0.236 
  8 OR                OR      4.57   1.27  
  9 OR_GR_50_50       GR      0.413  0.212 
 10 OR_GR_50_50       OR      3.83   1.76  
 11 OR_IK_25_75       IK      0.143  0.0410
 12 OR_IK_25_75       OR      5.55   0.694 
 13 OR_IK_GR_33_33_33 GR      0.300  0.0761
 14 OR_IK_GR_33_33_33 IK      0.0572 0.0496
 15 OR_IK_GR_33_33_33 OR      4.00   0.484
```

I am using the following code, but it is not working:

```
    DMN_Graph <- DMN_Graph %>%
    reshape(idvar= "Partner",timevar = "Crop" ,direction="wide")
```

I need the end result to be like this (this is a small representation of how it should be)

```
       Partner    GR_DM  GR_SD_DM    LU_DM  LU_SD_DM LU_GR_50_50_DM LU_GR_50_50_SD_DM 
     1      GR 2.903483 0.7713203       NA        NA      2.2413259         0.4767502       
     2      LU       NA        NA 3.012506 0.3369118      0.7057679         0.4584558       
     3      OR       NA        NA       NA        NA             NA                NA             
     4      IK       NA        NA       NA        NA             NA                NA
```

but what it returns to me is

```
    # A tibble: 4 x 3
     Partner `DM.1:9` `SD_DM.1:9`
    <fct>   <fct>    <fct>      
    1 GR      NA       NA         
    2 IK      NA       NA         
    3 LU      NA       NA         
    4 OR      NA       NA
```

could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses the `tidyr` package which *'replaces `reshape2` (2010-2014) and `reshape` (2005-2010)'* (more can be found [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/#related-work)).

This is what you should do:

```
library(tidyr) # 1.1.0

DMN_Graph_wide <– DMN_Graph %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Crop, values_from = c(DM, SD_DM))
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 19
  Partner DM_GR DM_IK DM_LU DM_LU_GR_50_50 DM_LU_GR_75_25 DM_OR DM_OR_GR_50_50
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>
1 GR        2.9 NA    NA             2.24            1.85 NA             0.413
2 IK       NA    2.79 NA            NA              NA    NA            NA    
3 LU       NA   NA     3.01          0.706           1.63 NA            NA    
4 OR       NA   NA    NA            NA              NA     4.57          3.83 
# … with 11 more variables...
```

The rows and columns are ordered slightly differently, but if we add some 'rearranging' functions we can get your desired output:

```
DMN_Graph_wide %>%
  dplyr::select(Partner, DM_GR, SD_DM_GR, DM_LU, SD_DM_LU, DM_LU_GR_50_50, SD_DM_LU_GR_50_50) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(factor(Partner, levels = c("GR", "LU", "OR", "IK")))
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
  Partner DM_GR SD_DM_GR DM_LU SD_DM_LU DM_LU_GR_50_50 SD_DM_LU_GR_50_50
  <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>             <dbl>
1 GR        2.9    0.771 NA      NA              2.24              0.477
2 LU       NA     NA      3.01    0.337          0.706             0.458
3 OR       NA     NA     NA      NA             NA                NA    
4 IK       NA     NA     NA      NA             NA                NA
```

You can play around with `select()` and `arrange()` - they are from the `dplyr` package. Note, that the above code doesn't essentially change your wide data format; it just arranges it slightly differently - `DMN_Graph_wide` is all you need.

The only thing my code does not do is give the column names you wanted (`DM_GR` instead of `GR_DM`). You can read about possible solutions to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58183595/13445313).

---

For the future, on SO it is helpful to provide data with `dput(DMN_Graph)`:

```
> dput(DMN_Graph)
structure(list(Crop = c("GR", "IK", "LU", "LU_GR_50_50", "LU_GR_50_50", 
"LU_GR_75_25", "LU_GR_75_25", "OR", "OR_GR_50_50", "OR_GR_50_50", 
"OR_IK_25_75", "OR_IK_25_75", "OR_IK_GR_33_33_33", "OR_IK_GR_33_33_33", 
"OR_IK_GR_33_33_33"), Partner = c("GR", "IK", "LU", "GR", "LU", 
"GR", "LU", "OR", "GR", "OR", "IK", "OR", "GR", "IK", "OR"), 
    DM = c("2.9000", "2.7900", "3.0100", "2.2400", "0.7060", 
    "1.8500", "1.6300", "4.5700", "0.4130", "3.8300", "0.1430", 
    "5.5500", "0.3000", "0.0572", "4.0000"), SD_DM = c("0.7710", 
    "0.2790", "0.3370", "0.4770", "0.4580", "0.1450", "0.2360", 
    "1.2700", "0.2120", "1.7600", "0.0410", "0.6940", "0.0761", 
    "0.0496", "0.4840")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```